# How can I change the default margin in class columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple question. I am creating a simple cart and I use bootstrap as my CSS framework.
Now my question is I want to disable the margin-left in my columns in displaying the shopping cart items. I want to remove the margin in the thumbnail display.

Here's my simple code

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">

    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if it is only in a specific page, you can just add one more class selector to it.

Assume that we want to change col-sm-3

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 myCSSClass">
     Some HTML
 </div>

 <!-- Your CSS -->
 .col-sm-3 .myCSSClass
 {
     margin-left:0px !important;
 }
```

or you may want to change default col-sm-3 
then just apply this on your css file

```
 .col-sm-3
 {
     margin-left:0px !important;
 }
```

Finally I am not recommend the !important but it may be a solution for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own style element just simply like this

```
<div class="col-m-3 margin"></div>

.col-m-3 .margin
{
margin-left:0px;
//to remove border
border:none;
}
```